# How to merge 4 chrome tabs into 1 tab?

Tags: google-chrome

I'm in Dashcam Project, I need to show 4 Chrome browser tabs into 1 tab and show all of the page of each tab in to one tab, is there any tips and trick for doing this? or do I need a software tools for doing this?

I need advice.

many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several Chrome extensions available that offer tab management and merging capabilities. These extensions can help you combine or organize multiple tabs into one tab or group. You can search the Chrome Web Store for extensions like "TabMerger," "Tab Grouping," or similar terms to find options that suit your needs.